# How to get rid of persistent per-site meta reminder message

Tags: feature-request, design, per-site-meta, system-message

I just went on Woodworking SE and this message is at the top of the page, wherever I go.
[image: pic]
I find it kind of annoying.
I suggest adding a x for dismissing the message.

Comment: The message is permanent only for the first 30 days. That's [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91026/visit-meta-sidebar-element-on-beta-sites).